# R script that generates pdf in SSIS

Tags: r, pdf, ssis

I have SSIS package that gets data into database and then executes R Script. R script creates new folder (names it based on the current date) and generate some pdf files into this folder. I have deployed this package on server and created Job that executes it every night. The problem is that each morning I am finding only empty folders (with correct date name) without any pdf files. However, If I execute that package manually in Visual Studio it works fine and pdfs are there. Am I missing something here? I appreciate every answer.

**EDIT**

When I execute manually it is directly on the server

Package looks like this
[image]

and here is my R script

```
dir.create(file.path(output.path, date))
library(RODBC)
conn <- odbcConnect("Azure", uid = "aaaaa", pwd = "aaaaa")
etldata <- sqlFetch(conn,"dbo.EtlLogsData", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

pdf(paste('ETL_Duration_For_Effective_Date_', date,'.pdf',sep = ""),
  width = 12,
  height = 8,
  paper = 'special')

par(mar = c(5, 17, 5, 3))

plot(c(min(etldata_day$st_sec), max(etldata_day$et_sec)),
   c(sn[1], sn[1]),
   ylim = c(0, n),
   yaxt = 'n',
   xaxt = 'n',
   ylab = '',
   xlab = 'Time',
   main = paste('ETL Duration With Effective Date ', date, sep = ""))
   abline(h = sn, untf = FALSE, col = "gray90")

for (i in 1:n){
lines(c(etldata_day$st_sec[i], etldata_day$et_sec[i]),
      c(sn[i], sn[i]),
      type = "l", lwd = 2)
arrows(etldata_day$st_sec[i], sn[i],
       etldata_day$et_sec[i], sn[i],
       length = 0.025, angle = 90, lwd = 2)
arrows(etldata_day$et_sec[i], sn[i],
       etldata_day$st_sec[i], sn[i],
       length = 0.025, angle = 90, lwd = 2)
}

# Print y axis labels
axis(2, at = sn, labels = etldata_day$TaskName, las = 1, cex.axis = 1)

# Print x axis labels
xat <- seq(from = min(etldata_day$st_sec), to = max(etldata_day$et_sec),      length.out = 10)
xlabels <- secondsToString(xat)
axis(1, at = xat, labels = substr(xlabels,1,8), cex.axis = 1)
dev.off()
```

After plot() I use some FOR cycles, and LINES(),

Comment: @Gregor I am sorry, I edited my question.